# Automatic deploy on commit

Tags: javascript, html, git, deployment

I want to find a solution, to automatic deploy static site (HTML+JS) when I'm doing a commit. I'm using git. 
It would be great to upload only those files that have been changed.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a  Gist](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044)  using the deployment with automatic git commit.